# Named parameters in Perl

Tags: perl, parameter-passing

I'm attempting to use named parameters in Perl. I've been using [http://perldesignpatterns.com/?NamedArguments](http://web.archive.org/web/20160920193219/http://perldesignpatterns.com/?NamedArguments) as a reference.

It seems to make sense. However, I can't seem to actually get the values sent in.

I have tried changing to `$args{'name'}`, `$args{"name"}` as well and no luck. I just can't seem to get the values passed in. Which direction do I need to look in to figure out what on earth is happening?

#### File doh.pm

```
package doh;
sub new ()
{
   my %args = @_;
   $name = $args{name};
   print $name;
}
1;
__END__
```

#### File test.pl

```
use warnings;
use doh;
$trial = doh::;
$trial->new(name => "Tyson");
```

No output is printed when test.pl is run.

Comment: `$trial = doh::; $trial->new` is a weird way of doing `doh->new`!!!

Comment: Good thing Perl ignores prototypes on methods since your prototype is wrong. Get rid of it!

Comment: At as very simplistic level, the reason I was using the "$trial = doh::" is because I have some stuff setup that the doh would be replaceable with another package, but the other package contains the same functions/proceudres/methods.Rather than having to replace doh-> with duh (throughout the whole script) I thought it would be more "readable" to use a generic name as the $<var> and treat it as an alias (if that's the right term) of the package. I use perl for scripting a lot, but more of the OO and other specifics of it I haven't quite learned the nuances yet.

Comment: Clearly I haven't shown the actual script I'm using this in, but I really can't due to work. I will ask what you mean by "my prototype is wrong" ikegami. Also prior to yesterday I didn't even know you could do "$trial = doh::;" I just tried it and it did something like what I was kinda wanting to do.

Comment: You gave a prototype on `new` telling Perl it accepts no args. That's obviously not true.

Comment: So in this case, what would I put in there a $? I.E. sub new ($)?

Comment: You shouldn't be using one at all (`sub new { }`). Prototypes are ignored for method calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `$trial = doh::;`, but your main problem is you're trying to process arguments before dealing with your method invocant.

First, start every Perl file with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Yes, you need both.

When calling methods in Perl (as opposed to ordinary subroutines) the thing on the left-hand side of the `->` operator (the *invocant*) is pushed onto the beginning of the argument list. So you need to get that off the list first. In the case of your constructor method, the invocant will usually be the class name. For an instance method, it will be the object itself. So

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;

    print "name is: $args{name}\n";
}
```

(If you don't want to use `shift`, you could also just write `my ( $class, %args ) = @_;` )

For instance methods, the convention is to name the variable `$self`.

Notice also that I've removed the parens after the subroutine name; these don't have any function for OO methods and they probably don't do what you think, anyway.

Comment: Of course, considering the OP's code isn't really an object constructor, there's no reason to use OOisms in it at all.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I figured he wants to make it into a constructor eventually. :)

Comment: He totally called it as a method, and that was his problem.